# Reading Hex as String

Tags: assembly, masm32

im not good in coding in assembly, I just need this to write in assembly anyways here is what I am trying to do. (I'm using Masm32)

```
.data
        Msg    db    31h, 00h, 32h, 00h, 33h  ;convert this to string which "123"

    .code

    start:

        invoke MessageBox, 0, addr Msg, 0, 0
        call ExitProcess
    end start
```

As you can see each character or byte is separated with a null byte, it can only show one byte, "1" instead of "123"

If only I can concatenate each readable byte until it reaches the end of the string.

```
mov ebx, offset Msg
mov ecx, ebx
add ebx, 2
invoke lstrcat, ebx, ecx
```

Maybe add a loop also, I just don't know the better way to code it or if you have a better solution that you can share.

Comment: I would have said it looks like Unicode, but there's an odd number of bytes (the last byte doesn't have a `00`). Is that a transcription error?

Comment: Why are you doing windows programming in assembly? Have you been talking to [Steve Gibson](https://www.grc.com/smgassembly.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work on the string, you need to know the length of the string.  This is done by using NULL to terminate the string.  Functions that do not take the string length as an argument, will look for a 00H, and print the string up to it, that is what MessageBox is doing, printing "1" and seeing the next character is 00h, stops printing.

In your case, where there is no an NULL terminator at the end of the string, we can get the string length at Assembly time with the symbol "$" which is the current value of the location counter.

```
Msg         db    31h, 00h, 32h, 00h, 33h  ;convert this to string which "123"
Msg_Len     equ $ - Msg
```

Which means, take the address of $ and subtract the address of Msg, and replace Msg_Len with that value.

```
include masm32rt.inc

.data
Msg         db    31h, 00h, 32h, 00h, 33h ;convert this to string which "123"
Msg_Len     equ $ - Msg

.data?
Msg_New     db  Msg_Len + 1 dup (?)

.code
start:

    xor     ecx, ecx                ; index into source array
    xor     edx, edx                ; index into dest array
    lea     esi, Msg
    lea     edi, Msg_New
ConvertIt:
    mov     al, byte ptr[esi + ecx] ; get byte at pointer + index
    cmp     al, 0                   ; is it a 0?
    jne     @F                      ; no, add it to dest array
    inc     ecx                     ; yes, increase source index
    jmp     CheckForEnd             ; check to see if at end

@@:
    mov     byte ptr [edi + edx], al; add byte to dest array
    inc     ecx                     ; increase both indexes
    inc     edx                     ; 

CheckForEnd:
    cmp     ecx, Msg_Len            ; check for end - if ecx == Msg_Len we are done
    jne     ConvertIt               ; if ecx != Msg_Len, continue loop

    mov     byte ptr [edi + edx], 0 ; don't forget to NULL terminate dest string

    invoke  MessageBox, HWND_DESKTOP, offset Msg_New, NULL, MB_OK
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

This can be done with less code and "converting" the string "in place" but that is beyond the scope here.

@Nik, some of us love Assembly and don't use anything else.